# Reactjs - Re render data on button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using an API to fetch some data. When the page loads it fetches some random data, but I want to allow the user to sort the data by clicking a button. I have made a function to sort these data from the API I am using. What I want to do now is: When the button to sort data is clicked, I want the new data to be replaced with the old data.

Here is my current code:

```js
class Data extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
         data: [],
         offset: 0, perPage: 12 // ignore these two
      };
   }

   // The random data that I want to be displayed on page load
   receivedData() {
      axios
         .get(`https://corona.lmao.ninja/v2/jhucsse`)
         .then(res => {
            const data = res.data;
            
            const slice = data.slice(this.state.offset, this.state.offset + this.state.perPage) // ignore this
            const postData = slice.map(item => 
               <tr key={Math.random()}>
                  <td>{item.province}, {item.country}</td>
                  <td>{item.stats.confirmed}</td>
                  <td>{item.stats.deaths}</td>
                  <td>{item.stats.recovered}</td>
               </tr>
            )

            this.setState({
               pageCount: Math.ceil(data.length / this.state.perPage), // ignore this
               
               postData
            })
         });
   }

   // The data to be sorted when the "country" on the table head is clicked
   sortData() {
      axios
         .get(`https://corona.lmao.ninja/v2/jhucsse`)
         .then(res => {
            const data = res.data;

            var someArray = data;
            function generateSortFn(prop, reverse) {
               return function (a, b) {
                  if (a[prop] < b[prop]) 
                     return reverse ? 1 : -1;
                  if (a[prop] > b[prop]) 
                     return reverse ? -1 : 1;
                  return 0;
               };
            }
            // someArray.sort(generateSortFn('province', true))

            const tableHead = <tr>
               <th onClick={() => someArray.sort(generateSortFn('province', true))}>Country</th>
               <th>Confirmed Cases</th>
               <th>Deaths</th>
               <th>Recovered</th>
            </tr>

            this.setState({
               tableHead
            })
         });
   }

   componentDidMount() {
      this.receivedData()
      this.sortData() // This function should be called on the "Country - table head" click
   }

   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <table>
               <tbody>
                  {this.state.tableHead}

                  {this.state.postData}
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </div>
      )
   }
}

export default Data;
```

Comment: *Your state has variously-mismatched keys.* Look at `render()`.  You have: `{this.state.tableHead}` and `{this.state.postData}`. BUT, then you do `this.setState({postData});` in `receivedData()` and `this.setState({tableHead})` in `sortData()`.  That needs to be `this.setState({'tableHead':tableHead, 'postData':somePostdata})` and likewise for `postData`'s call.

Comment: Let me know if that helps, I can thresh it out into a full answer if it's good?

Comment: @HoldOffHunger I cannot get it to work using the instructions you gave

Comment: What's happening, then?  I mean, you're setting your state up with different keys in your constructor, in your api calls, and in your render() calls.  There's no way that can possible work?

Answer (score 0):

Think a litte bit different. In the componentDidMount get you're Data in some form. Set it with setState only the raw Data not the html. Then resort the data on button click. React rerenders if the state changes automatically

```
class Data extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
     data
   }
 }

 getData() {
  fetchData('url').then(res) {
   this.setState({data: res.data})
  }
 }

 componentDidMount() {
  this.getData()
 }

 sort() {
  let newSorted = this.state.data.sort //do the sorting here
  this.setState({data: newSorted})
 }

 render() {
  return() {
   <table>
    <tablehead><button onClick={this.sort.bind(this)}/></tablehead>
    {this.state.data.map(data => {
     return <tablecell>{data.name}</tablecell>
    })}
   </table>
  }
 }
}
```